# Noun to describe a 'radial shape'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I want to use this in the following sentence:

> The shape the blocks make together when seen from above resembles a **radial**.

**[Radial](http://goo.gl/mbSHz)** adjective: a radial pattern or design consists of straight lines that all go out from the center of a circle

Comment: It'd help which blocks you're talking about. The Electrostatic flux lines are also stretched radially outwards.

Comment: Do you mean "the shape of the blocks put together..."?

Comment: The objects themselves aren't that important, just that the when seen from, they collectively seem to creat a shape that resembles a radial/wheel design. In other words, they are arranged in a radial pattern. The blocks are office cubicles, if that helps.

Comment: Well in the above sentence, 'radial' is actually being used as a noun. Whether or not it's allowed to be is another question, but it's not taking the place of an adjective in your example sentence. You're using it as a noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase ***like spokes on a wheel*** is often used to describe this configuration.

You can look through several published instances of this phrase at [this Google books search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22like%20spokes%20on%20a%20wheel%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1942,cd_max:2002&lr=lang_en). Sometimes the expression is used to describe an architectural concept (also called *hub and spokes*, as in the image shown below on the left); other times, it's used to describe the physical appearance of something (as in the image on the right, which was taken from a 1948 [*Popular Mechanics*](http://books.google.com/books?id=8tgDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA73&dq=%22like%20spokes%20on%20a%20wheel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UwxiUcfxEeqU2wWRj4CYAQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAzg8#v=onepage&q=%22like%20spokes%20on%20a%20wheel%22&f=false) magazine, where it was described as in the article as *“radiating outward like spokes on a wheel”*).

[image: images of "spokes on a wheel"]

The expression can be found even in culinary circles:

[image]
<sup>(from *Vegetarian Times* magazine, Sept 1992)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, I think I can work this into my sentence perfectly. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather rewrite the sentence as follows:

> Seen from above, the blocks together have a radial shape.

[Radial](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/radial_2) is already used as noun, but it has a different meaning.

> a car tyre with strong parts inside that point away from the outside part and make the tyre stronger and safer